# Multirow: column borders missing

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I'm not getting column borders correctly in the following table. I'm using `multirow` package. Also, I want the '123' in the big cell to be centered, but it is misaligned. I'm not sure how to fix this. Here's what I have:

```
    \begin{table} 
    \centering
      \hline
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
      1 & 2 & 3& \\ \hline
      1 & & 3 &\\  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
      1 & \multirow{-3}{*}{123} & 3& \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
```

Note that I have no multiple column cells in the table -- only multiple row cells.

Comment: If you write `\multirow{-2}` instead of `\multirow{-3}`, it's correct. The problem with the borders is what? The missing `\hline` above the first row? Just write it.

Comment: Thanks. No, not the missing \hline. I'm missing the all of the vertical lines separating the columns except for the leftmost one.

Comment: I don't miss them. Could you provide a minimal (non)working example?

Comment: How to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you like to achieve something like this:

[image]

For it I just correct  errors in your MWE: `\hline` before tabular, number of rows in `multirow`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3     \\      \hline
      1 &   & 3     \\      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
      1 & \multirow{-2}{*}{123}
            & 3     \\      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Preview package in preamble I added just to show table alone.